# Google Cloud TextToSpeech : java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to run the TextToSpeech code from **Google Cloud TextToSpeech** Service.

Curently stuck at **Authentication** part referring link [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

**Below is the Code :**

```
public class TexttoSpeech {

/** Demonstrates using the Text-to-Speech API. */
public static void getAudio() throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
 // Below Line is Point of Error in Code 
    try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
        // Set the text input to be synthesized
        SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder().setText("Hello, World!").build();

        // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml voice 
         //gender
        // ("neutral")
        VoiceSelectionParams voice =
                VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
                        .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                        .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
                        .build();

        // Select the type of audio file you want returned
        AudioConfig audioConfig =
                AudioConfig.newBuilder().setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3).build();

        // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
        // audio file type
        SynthesizeSpeechResponse response =
                textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);

        // Get the audio contents from the response
        ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();
        byte[] audioArray=audioContents.toByteArray();
        String converted= Base64.encodeBase64String(audioArray);
        playAudio(converted);

        // Write the response to the output file.
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.mp3")) {
            out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
        }
    }
}

public static void playAudio(String base64EncodedString){
    try
    {
        String url = "data:audio/mp3;base64,"+base64EncodedString;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

**But getting below error on :**

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available 
if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable 
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. 
See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more 
information.
```

**Also tried Explicit credentials :**

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
 fun authExplicit() {
    val projectID = "texttospeech-12345"  // dummy id
//        val imageUri: Uri = 
Uri.fromFile(File("file:\\android_asset\\service_account_file.json"))
//        val path=File(imageUri.path).absolutePath
    // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
    // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment 
 variable.
    val credentials = 
GoogleCredentials.fromStream(mContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.service_account_file))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))
    val storage: Storage =      
StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectID).setCredentials(credentials)
               .build().service
    println("Buckets:")

   // Error at storage.lists()
    val buckets: Page<Bucket> = storage.list()
    for (bucket in buckets.iterateAll()) {
        println(bucket.toString())
    }
}
```

**But on device it gives error like :**

```
  Error getting access token for service account: 
  Unable to resolve host "oauth2.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname, iss: 
  xyz@texttospeech-12345.iam.serviceaccount.com
```

**And on Emulator the error is :**

```
 xxxxxxxxx does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.
```

Please let me know if you guys need something more.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

**Also if I run below command in Cloud SDK :**

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

**I get this but I didnt understood what its trying to say** [image]

Comment: You may want to re-read: [Best practices to securely authenticate applications in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications) as generally interacting with Google Cloud is done via PC / command line / your own cloud server. Loading up the service account keys into a mobile app means that anyone who get those service acct keys uses your billing account and your money.

Comment: I went through the link above and got the gist of the flow , so the gcloud part was something that I dont need to focus on. But I need to focus on the JWT part with my service json file. But bit confused to what to do with the JWT as I don't have any API to call. So do I need to add the JWT file contents in the json at the end.Is my assumption correct.

Comment: You should clarify if this is for test/dev only or you need the client to be similar to production, as usually for production there is a cloud server between the Google API and the Android client to allow for fine grain authorization and avoid/monitor overspending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the credentials while creating the client connection.

```
TextToSpeechSettings settings = TextToSpeechSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(authExplicit("JSON FILE PATH")))
        .build();
try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create(settings)) {
    // ... rest of your code
}
// ... rest of your code
```

And

```
public static GoogleCredentials authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {

    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

    return credentials;
}
```

`GoogleCredentials` imported from [Google Auth Library For Java OAuth2 HTTP](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/1.8.1)

**N.B** You need to make sure you are able to fetch the JSON file in your application.

Comment: That just worked, just downloaded the grpc-okhttp dependency and its done. Thanks man. I was stuck in this for more than 4 days.

Comment: Mention not. Glad to know it helped you :) .